# Git multiple repositories (remote copy of local changes of 3rd repository)

Tags: git, repository

This is a scenario that keeps popping up for me, but I'll use a specific example that I'm working with now.

I have a local clone of a remote repository (in this case Marlin). I make local configuration changes and build. These are of no interest to Marlin users, but I want them version controlled. So I create a branch and push that to a repository on my own server (not on GitHub).

I have this set up and working with my initial branch. Later, I check out the repository from my server but it has no knowledge of the original Marlin repository, either for existing branches or new branches of Marlin branches.

I'm looking for workflow recommendations that will allow me to:
1. Pull updates from the Marlin repository into my own branch
2. Create a new branch from the Marlin repository that will be version controlled in my server's repository

Sorry if this is basic stuff but this multi-repository paradigm is new for me.

Git versions:
local 2.20.1
server 2.7.4

Answer (score 0):

Just add the original gh repo as a new remote to this new repo and then you will be able to fetch from it and stuff.

```
git remote add original https://github/blahblah.git
git fetch original
```

And there you would see the stuff in the original github repo (the remote can be called whatever you want... original, upstream, gh, whatever you feel like).

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is perfectly reasonable.  This is a standard workflow in open source software when a repository is forked, so you have two remote repositories, one that you own (the `origin`), and one that someone else owns (the `upstream`).

The workflow might look something like this:

```
# Clone down the Marlin repository
git clone https://github.com/person/marlin.git

# Move into the repository's directory
cd marlin

# List your current remotes
git remote -v

### Example output:
### origin      https://github.com/person/marlin.git (fetch)
### origin      https://github.com/person/marlin.git (push)
```

As you can see, you now have one remote called "origin".  But this is the one that someone else owns, so let's call it "upstream" as is the classic name

```
# Rename the "origin" remote to "upstream"
git remote rename origin upstream
```

Now you would go on your server and create a repository, then get the clone url.  Once you have that url, you can add it as a second remote like this:

```
# Add a second remote to your repository
git remote add origin https://example.com/foo/marlin.git
```

And finally, push whatever branches you want to the origin repo that you owns

```
# Push the master branch to the repo you owns
git push origin master
```